# Copy data from one data-frame to another and substitute the data depending on values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df1`

the head of `df1` looks like:

```
        date    last_location   cost_factor is_reporting
0 24/02/2014              510        1.0026            0
1 25/02/2014              498        0.9981            0
2 26/02/2014              492        0.9986            4
3 27/02/2014              489        0.9986            4
4 28/02/2014              493        0.9986            0
5 03/03/2014              485        0.9986            0
```

and the head of `df2` looks like:

```
        date   dept     
0 24/02/2014      A            
1 25/02/2014      A             
2 26/02/2014      B             
3 27/02/2014      B                
4 28/02/2014      B               
5 03/03/2014      C
```

I would like to add the is_reporting column from `df1` to `df2` but instead of using the value from `df1` I would like to insert a `1` if the value is anything other than `0`.  So the desired result would look like:

```
        date   dept  is_reporting
0 24/02/2014      A             0
1 25/02/2014      A             0 
2 26/02/2014      B             1 
3 27/02/2014      B             1    
4 28/02/2014      B             0   
5 03/03/2014      C             0
```

I think I need to copy `is_reporting` into df2 from df1 and use `replace` but I do not know how to replace any value greater than 0 with 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and replace values in column `is_reporting` by compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with casting to integers and [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for overwrite column:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1[['date','is_reporting']], on='date', how='left')
df3 = df3.assign(is_reporting = df3['is_reporting'].ne(0).astype(int))
```

Or swap operations:

```
df1 = df1.assign(is_reporting = df1['is_reporting'].ne(0).astype(int))
df3 = df2.merge(df1[['date','is_reporting']], on='date', how='left')
```

---

```
print (df3)
         date dept  is_reporting
0  24/02/2014    A             0
1  25/02/2014    A             0
2  26/02/2014    B             1
3  27/02/2014    B             1
4  28/02/2014    B             0
5  03/03/2014    C             0
```